# Dom xpath query is not working

Tags: php, xpath

This is my code

```
 $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

  $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

  //get all the h2's with an id
  $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//p[text() = "Site"]');
```

But It dose not return any result
Here is the html

```
<p class="devby">
<br clear="all"/>
<br>Site Developed by <span class="footcolor"><a href="http://www.google.com/">google.com</a></span>

</p>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the information you want to extract is not generated via JavaScript?

Comment: your comment in the PHP code says you want to get some `<h2/>` elements, yet there are none in your HTML code and your XPath selects `<p/>` elements. So what is your actual expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath expects the p tag to have the exact content "Site". You can make it a little more loose by defining `contains`, which only requires the string you are looking for to be present somewhere within the tag and not be its exclusive content.
So you could check for `//p/br[contains(text(),"Site")]` ?